# Passing multiple variables in function with *args variable

Tags: python, function, args

I'm new to python. Look at this script please:

```
def myfunc(*args):  
    print len(args)
    if args == 3:
        for arg in args:
            print arg
    else:
        print "exit"
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
myfunc(a, b, c)
```

As you can see, the number of arguments passing to function is three. Now condition `args==3` is `True` but the `else` portion is executed. While on other hand if `if` condition is false then that portion of code is executed and `else` is skipped.

Can you explain why the `if` statement is executed on False condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must be doing `len(args)==3` instead of `args==3`:

```
if len(args)==3:
```

the condition `args==3` is never going to be true as `args` becomes a tuple inside the function.

so even if you pass `myfunc(3)`, then also you'll be matching `(3,)==3`, which is `False`.

Comment: ahhhhh thank you so much.After printing args and len(args), now I get the idea why. :)

Answer (score 7):

No, `args == 3` is  *not* `True`. You probably meant `len(args) == 3`.

Comment: @savruk But only *very* maybe.

Comment: totally agree there, as I didn't read the question well. My sorry

Comment: @cdarke What insight should I get from this? The error is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `len(args) == 3` instead of `args == 3` because if you use `args` then it is a list of tupple and if you check against it must go to `else` condition.

```
def myfunc(*args):

    if len(args) == 3:
        for arg in args:
            print arg
    else:
        print "exit"
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
myfunc(a, b, c)
```

This code give you an expected result.

Comment: how's your answer different from the other two answers?and `args` is not a `list of tuple` , it's just a `tuple`.